# Git - How to reject commits containing tabs on origin

Tags: git, githooks

Can someone share a "origin" side hook that checks if the received commit introduces a wrong whitespace character (in my case tab) and rejects that push?

I can't do it pre-commit because I have people on the team who are, well... oh, nevermind. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right place to do this is the `update` hook. I haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
branch=$1
oldrev=$2
newrev=$3

if git diff $oldrev..$newrev | grep -P '\+.*\t'; then
    echo When updating ref $branch: diff $oldrev..$newrev introduces tabs
    exit 1
fi
```